# Google PageSpeed and ImageMagick : png compression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, png, carrierwave, pagespeed

I'm checking my website with Google PageSpeed and I have the following warning :

`Losslessly compressing image.png could save 802B (31% reduction).`

This png file is uploaded on my Rails website with carrierwave. When the image is uploaded, I run the equivalent of `convert -strip -quality 100 -resize "90x90^" -gravity center -extent 90x90 image.png final_image.png`

But it's not enough for Google.

What do I miss ?

Thank you!

Comment: Try running some PNG optimizer (PNGOUT, PNGCRUSH, PngOptim ...)

Answer (score 2):

Please see PageSpeed documentation https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages:

> **Recommendations**
>
> You should perform both basic and advanced optimization on all images.
>   Basic optimization includes cropping unnecessary space, reducing color
>   depth to the lowest acceptable level, removing image comments, and
>   saving the image to an appropriate format. You can perform basic
>   optimization with any image editing program, such as GIMP. Advanced
>   optimization involves further (lossless) compression of JPEG and PNG
>   files.
>
> **Use an image compressor**
>
> Several tools are available that perform further, lossless compression
>   on JPEG and PNG files, with no effect on image quality. For JPEG, we
>   recommend [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/) or [jpegoptim](http://freshmeat.net/projects/jpegoptim/) (available on Linux only;
>   run with the --strip-all option). For PNG, we recommend [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)
>   or [PNGOUT](http://www.advsys.net/ken/util/pngout.htm).

Answer (score -1):

For google pagespeed, use PNG optimizer tool like [Jpeg Compressor](https://jpegcompressor.com/). It provide further lossless compression, which can help improve your website performance. Additionally check you perform both basic and advanced optimization as recommended by [Google's PageSpeed documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed)